# Is there any matrix for which $A^{-1} = - A^t$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

where $A \in GL_{3}(\mathbb{R})$

My idea:

$A^T \cdot A  = I$

and we know that

$A^{-1} \cdot A = I$ which implifies that,

$A^T \cdot A  = I$

$(A^T⋅A)⋅A^{−1}=(I)⋅A^{−1}$

$A^{T}⋅(A⋅A^{−1})=A{−1}$

$A^T⋅(I)=A^{−1}$

$A^T=A^{−1}$

I'm not sure that my idea above is a correct proof to the problem above, that there is no $A$ where $A^{-1} = - A^t$ and $A \in GL_{3}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: $AA^t$ is always positive semi-definite.

Comment: You need to start with $A^tA=-I$, not $A^tA=I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof starts with $A^t \cdot A  = I$. This is not correct. Correct is  $A^t \cdot A  = -I$.

Then $A^t \cdot A $ is positive semi-definite, but $-I$ is negative definite, a contradiction.

Comment: Is there any other proof with out using this definition about being semi-definite? We still didn't learn it, so if I calculate $A^t \cdot A  = -I$ do I get the right answer?

Comment: See my second answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $( \cdot, \cdot)$ denote the usual inner product on $ \mathbb R^3.$ Let $x \in \mathbb R^3$ and $x \ne 0.$ Then

$$(A^tAx,x)=(Ax,Ax) \ge 0$$

and

$$(A^tAx,x)=(-Ix,x)=-(x,x) <0,$$

A contradiction.